# making a link to another tab with href title and target

Tags: html

im new to coding and i got an assignment that I didn't understand the outcome of.
heres a link to the solution: https://gyazo.com/061d8e2e23070bf5c13d737518175362
 i dont understand why the marked ">" is required. my solution to the issue before was : https://gyazo.com/63563dceafa3c14852a78095b24bd786
can someone explain to me the difference between the two

Comment: Please copy the code into the question itself

Answer (score 1):

Bocman in your first solution you missed to close the tag. You are using anchor tag and its syntax is this

`<a> </a>`

and you are making href you have to closed it at the end. That was only the syntax that you was not following.